# Microsoft Flow - The template language expression cannot be evaluated because property 'location' doesn't exist

Tags: automation, power-automate

I am getting below error when trying to run Microsoft Flow. I accessing Longitude and Latitude through email.
When executing it from machine or mobile I am getting this error. I have given permission for accessing the location still I am getting this error .

'The template language expression 'triggerBody()['location']['coordinates']['longitude']' cannot be evaluated because property 'location' doesn't exist, available properties are 'text'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after long time, I found that the problem was related to subscription & permission to access the details (Location - for longitude and latitude) from mobile device.

I changed my subscription ( to licensed one) and gave permission to Flow mobile app in Mobile -> Settings -> apps permission. This resolved my issue. Hope this might be helpful for someone with same issue.